# Stored Procedure return values with linq data context

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I am trying to access the return value of a stored procedure with Linq

```
DECLARE @ValidToken int = 0 //I have also tried using a bit instead of an int here.

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Tests WHERE TestToken = @Token)
    select @ValidToken = 1

return @ValidToken
```

This works when running the SP through sql studio. However I am trying to run it with linq using the datacontext class and it is always returning -1.

```
using (DataEntities dataEntities = new DataEntities())
    {
        int query = data.ValidateToken(id);
        Response.Write(query.ToString());
    }
```

query will always equal -1 and I am not sure why.

I have looked online and it would appear that there are easier ways to get the return value however I would rather stick to Linq as that is what the rest of the program is using.

Comment: is that workf ro you ?/ or any other solution of answer?

Comment: I have tried the changes that you suggested but query will still always = -1

Comment: I've not done much stuff with linq to databases but I assume from looking at it that the DataEntities is some kind of generated class. Is it definitely doing the right thing or might you need to regenerate it or something? Sorry if this is a stupid comment but its just a thought and the bountying up makes you sound like any ideas/inspiration might help. :)

Comment: Please post the code of the implementation of ValidateToken().

Comment: Is `Tests` a view?, also shouldn't you query be `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Tests`

Comment: Database.ExecuteSqlCommand may give you what you're looking for, but it's not as nice as calling the SP as a method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456(v=vs.103).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: i think i don't quite get what the result should looks like should it only this one Value `ValidToken` or more?

Comment: I suspect the answer is you can't get return values from within DataEntities/Linq. I can't seem to get them from EF Code First either, only compelx/scaler types returned via select. You may have to bite the bullet and use a command object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you all using a stored procedure as function?

Though a stored procedure has `return`, it is not a function, so you should not use `return` to return data,

Rather, you should use Output parameters and other ways to return data, as [documented at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx)

And the use of `return` is [documented at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)

misusing `return` is probably the reason why LINQ does not understand your stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

this was I did and it worked.

In Sqlserver:

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidateToken]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Id int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Ret INT

SELECT
    @Ret = COUNT(*)
FROM Test

set @Ret =@Id+1;

select @Ret

END
```

In C#:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SergioEntities dm = new SergioEntities()) 
        {
            int? validToken = 1;

            int? a = dm.ValidateToken(validToken).First();

        }

    }
```

Give it a try :)

Comment: Hi Sergio thanks, it would appear that although this works, I am trying to get the sql return code from the stored procedure and when you run this the stored procedure actually returns two results - (@ ret) as well as the return code, however the block of c# only gets the value of @ret. This is a nice hack from a functional point of view but I really want to know how to access the return code of the stored procedure without having to return extra result sets.

Comment: @Jamesla you can delete the return statement.
Take a look here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/c4b85efc-a381-4595-8ae9-185378e4ef17

The solution passes by using the select statement instead of the return.

Comment: Ok I deleted the line "select @Ret as token;" from your example and it is returning -1 again.

Comment: @Jamesla I will edit this to the last working solution that I have on my pc.

Comment: Yes I tried the edit but when I execute it in sql studio manager it is returning a result and a return value. It is returning @ret as the result and then it is returning the actual return value. I am starting to wonder whether it is impossible to get the return value with the entityframework.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the RETURN 0/1 statements to SELECT 0/1

Comment: No that doesn't work either. I know it is not a problem with the stored procedure because when I run the sp in sql studio it returns the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with you code is you use `IF(query)` instead of that you need to user it like `IF EXISTS(query)` so you code will be like as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc]         
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @Ret INT

      //use of IF EXISTS instead of IF
      IF EXISTS(SELECT * from Tests WHERE TestToken = @Token)
        SELECT @Ret =  0
      ELSE
        SELECT @Ret =  1

      RETURN @Ret
END
```

Your code may look like,

```
using (TestDBDataContext db = new TestDBDataContext())
{
    //For Stored Procedure with Return value (for Integer)
    //returns Int
    var q = db.MyProc();
    Console.WriteLine(q);               

}
```

If this doesnt work than go for the other solutions

- Output Parameter
- Using Scalar-Values Functions

Which are discuss here : [**LINQ to SQL : Returning Scalar Value from Stored Procedure**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2009/04/10/linq-to-sql-returning-scalar-value-from-stored-procedure.aspx)

Comment: That also doesn't work. That doesn't work from sql either. It always returns 0 even with valid for some reason.

Comment: @Jamesla - I found issue with your code you need to use IF EXISTS instead of IF..check my updated answer and stored prceudre this will surely resolve your problem...

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the stored procedure but with the data entity framework because when the stored procedure is executed from sql management studio it gives me the correct return value. However in my program it is returning -1.

Comment: I am basically doing case 2 in your link identically however it doesnt work. That link is from 2009 so maybe something has changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

```tsql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc]         
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret INT

    // use of IF EXISTS instead of IF
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * from Tests WHERE TestToken = @Token)
        SELECT @Ret =  0
    ELSE
        SELECT @Ret =  1

    RETURN @Ret
END
```

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE - This reference code is useful only when Stored Procedure
> returning one row.

If you are using "select" in Stored procedure
here is the working code -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetData]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Id int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret INT 
    SELECT @Ret = COUNT(*) FROM Test 
    set @Ret =@Id+1;
    set @Ret1 =@Id+2; 
    select @Ret as Id, @Ret1 as Id2
END
```

C# code -

```
using (DataAccessDataContext db = new DataAccessDataContext())
{
   Cls_Response rtn = new Cls_Response();
   try
   { 
     var SP_data = db.sp_GetData(....params...);
     foreach (var c in SP_data)
     {
        rtn.Id = c.Id;
        rtn.Id2 = c.Id2;
        rtn.Status = true;
        rtn.Message = "success";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    rtn.Id = null;
    rtn.Id2 = null;
    rtn.Status = false;
    rtn.Message = ex.Message;
  }
  return rtn;
}

public class Cls_Response
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public long? Id2 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the be response -

```
{ 
    "Status": true,
    "Message": "success",
    "Id": 1,
    "Id2": 2
 }
```